# How to post a movie into different categories with php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Suppose I have a movie listing website and I want post a movie into different categories (eg: Drama , Action) And these categories should come from another table so that i can show a particular movie in two or more categories . how is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for, I believe is a many-to-many table relationship. You would have a table containing all of your movies (their names, duration, etc). And another table containing a list of all possible categories (action,drama,comedy,etc).

The trick will be to have an additional third table containing the movie to category relationship. You reference the movie's id and the category id, like this -

```
id | movie_id | category_id   
---|----------|-------------
 1 |    1     |      1 
 2 |    1     |      2
 3 |    2     |      3
 4 |    2     |      1
```

In this example, movie id 1 is in category 1 and 2. Movie id 2 is in category 1 and 3. So you see, a movie can be in more than one category.

Comment: @str - I guess... But for the sake of example I think it actually helps to understand the data... But you are correct - the `id` field has no real need to be there...

Comment: Well you are not duplicating the movie at all actually. All you are doing is creating a row for every category for every movie. The actual movie has only one reference in the movies table and the category has only one reference in the categories table. This **is** the correct way to do a many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 1):

You build a table that holds movie ids and category ids:

movie_category(movie_id*,category_id*)

'*' = (component of) PRIMARY KEY